Nativescript (V8.8) with Angular (V18) and plugin google-signin throws always Error: 10
I am currently developing a mobile app using the NativeScript framework, version 8.8, and Angular version 18 for the frontend.
I want to implement user authentication using the "google-signin" plugin. The documentation for the plugin can be found here: https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/google-signin
For Android, I have already set up a Firebase project and registered my app there. I also generated an SHA-1 fingerprint for my local keystore using the following command:
keytool -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore

I used "android" as the password, as recommended. I added the SHA-1 fingerprint to my Firebase project under the Android app settings. I also created an OAuth app in the Google Cloud Console and set up the OAuth consent screen accordingly.
Here's what I have in my app:
In the HTML file of my component, I added the Google Sign-In button:
<FlexboxLayout flexDirection="column" class="page">
    <GoogleSignInButton 
      colorScheme='auto' 
      colorStyle='standard' 
      (tap)="yourGoogleSigninFunction()">
    </GoogleSignInButton>
</FlexboxLayout>

The component's controller looks like this:
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Color, Page } from "@nativescript/core";
import { GoogleSignin } from "@nativescript/google-signin";

@Component({
  selector: "ns-users",
  templateUrl: "./users.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./users.component.scss"],
})
export class UsersComponent {
  constructor(page: Page) {
    page.actionBarHidden = true;
    page.androidStatusBarBackground = new Color("#cc9e26");
  }

  async yourGoogleSigninFunction() {
    console.log("yourGoogleSigninFunction");
    try {
      console.log("try");
      await GoogleSignin.configure({});
      console.log("configure");
      const user = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
      console.log("user", user);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
}

The issue:
When I start the app and click the Google Sign-In button, the usual Google Sign-In window opens, and I can log in successfully. However, after signing in, the console shows the following error:
Error: 10:

I'm testing on an Android emulator running Android 14 with Google Services.
How can I resolve this issue? Is there any way to further trace or identify the error? I’m stuck and appreciate any help.
Thank you!
